# setting the img src via php?

Tags: php

Here is my problem.

If I do:

```
  $imagePath = "images/spalt_images/body_images/525A.JPG";
              ?>
<img src="<?php $imagePath ?>" alt="front image" class="productImage"/> 
               <?php
```

Then my image does not show up.

However, if I do:

```
<img src="images/spalt_images/body_images/525A.JPG" alt="front image" class="productImage"/>
```

Then my image shows up just fine. Why would it not work with php?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo it:

```
<?php echo $imagePath ?>
```

or use a short tag (not recommended, but that's another discussion):

```
<?=$imagePath ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo $imagepath otherwise it won't 'print' it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<?php $imagePath ?>` in your code to `<?=$imagePath?>`, or add an echo if your server doesn't allow shorttags.